# Не работает navigator.userAgent()

Tags: javascript, safari

Попытался определить версию браузера с помощью:

```
document.write(navigator.userAgent);
```

Если захожу через Goole Chrome, то пишет:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36

Через Safari:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
> AppleWebKit/534.57.2 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Version/5.1.7 Safari/534.57.2

Искал по Интернету, везде пишут такой код, но он у меня не работает, т.к. в любом случае в строке находится искомая подстрока:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1)   
 {
  document.write("Safari");    
 }
```

Прочитал, что некоторые браузеры шифруются под другие.

Но как всё-же определить браузер со 100% точностью?

Comment: > но как всё-же определить браузер со 100% точностью? 

Никак. А зачем оно вам надо? 
Конкретно в вашем случае вам нужно еще посмотреть navigator.vendor.

Comment: Спасибо, @eicto, navigator.vendor помог.
Надо потому, что у сафари есть свои косяки при работе с javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript) можно найти более десятка реализаций - выбирайте, что понравится...

Comment: @deivan, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: в основном там пишут про userAgent, но есть и решение на базе jquery, правда,
оно не различает, например, яндекс и гугл браузеры,
а navigator.vendor не работает в ie.
В общем, хотелось бы не ухищеряться разными способами отыскивая имена браузеров, а иметь 100% вариант.